# Origin of term "reference" as in "pass-by-reference"

Tags: c#, java, c++, reference, pass-by-reference

Java/C# language lawyers like to say that their language passes references by value. This would mean that a "reference" is an object-pointer which is copied when calling a function.

Meanwhile, in C++ (and also in a more dynamic form in Perl and PHP) a reference is an alias to some other name (or run-time value in the dynamic case).

I'm interested in the etymology here. What were early uses of the term "reference"? Lets go for pre-Java, but if you know of pre-C++ uses, that would also interest me.

(I'm aware that vocabulary changes, etc, but I'm just interested in the history).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is an early usage of the term "call by reference" in the paper ["Semantic Models of Parameter Passing"](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/department/publications/reports/docs/CU-CS-016-73.pdf) by Richard E Fairley, March 1973.

In the early days, the terminology was inconsistent.  For example, the [Fortran 66 specification](http://www.fh-jena.de/~kleine/history/languages/ansi-x3dot9-1966-Fortran66.pdf) uses the phrases "association by name" and "association by value".  We would now call these "call by reference" and "call by value".  By contrast, [Algol 60 specification](http://www.masswerk.at/algol60/report.htm) (1962) used the terms "call by name" and "call by value" ... and neither of these are what we currently refer to as call by reference.

**EDIT**: To those who want to label the pioneers who specified Fortran 66 as confused for using the phrase "association by name", consider this:

1. The Fortran 66 was the first attempt to specify a language with (what we now call) call by reference.
2. It was only the second attempt to specify a language with subroutines that supported parameter passing.
3. Fortran 66's "association by name" can be viewed as a restricted (degenerate) form of Algol 60's "call by name".  The restriction being that in Fortran, the name had to be a simple variable or array name, where in Algol 60 it could be any expression.
4. It was not clear at the time (1966) that Algol 60's "call by name" was destined to be abandoned as a bad idea.  Indeed, when I studied Algol 60 as an undergraduate in 1977, I don't recall the lecturer presenting "call by name" as a bad idea.  (It was presented as difficult to understand ... but that's a different thing.)

Comment: Was "association by name" a reference (it sounds like an alias), or was it Algol-style call-by-value (which had all sorts of weird, described in another answer)?

Comment: @Paul - as I said, it was what we would now call "call by reference".  Check the linked spec.

Comment: Functional languages still use the terms "call-by-name" and "call-by-value", along with an additional classification: "call-by-need" (e.g. Haskell).

Comment: Good finds! But I wouldn't have said "inconsistent", which has a hint of being confused. It seems that different people consistently chose different nomenclature but knew they referred to the same terms, and that "call-by-reference" (or "pass-by-reference") won over "association."

Comment: Inconsistent != confused.  I am simply saying that no consensus had been reached.

Comment: Call-by-name in ALGOL 60 was emphatically NOT call-by-reference.  Read up on Jensen's Device.  (Google is your FRIEND.)

Answer (score 11):

(this reply relates to C# only, AFAIK)

Don't tell Eric Lippert that references are pointers ;-p They **happen** to be the same thing in MS C# / .NET, but that is an implementation detail. A reference is an opaque, safe "thing" that allows you to locate an object. A pointer is a memory address. They worked hard to make sure that you always know which you mean...

It would be entirely feasible to implement a CLI and compiler that **didn't** treat the two as the same; you would still be passing a *reference* to the value, though.

[References are not addresses](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/02/17/references-are-not-addresses.aspx)

Comment: Interesting. I believe the Java reference manual calls them pointers at some point - I'm more familiar with the Java case.

Comment: Great link from Eric Lippert!

Comment: A pointer is not a memory address. A pointer is often a memory address, but it is not a memory address. There are systems with segmented memory, for example, where a pointer might be an offset ("near" pointers) or a selector plus an offset ("far" pointers).

C# pointers have the same operational semantics as pointers, by definition. Pointers are references that can be rebound, and that's precisely what C# has.

Comment: @DrPizza - hmmm... goes to show what I know. Fair enough; I'll leave "as is" as a note relating to references vs memory addresses, but your point is noted. I would have to dig deep into the definitions to even try to challenge it, so I'll assume it is correct.

Answer (score 3):

I think the term you should use for historical searches is "call-by-reference" and not "pass-by-reference." For example, Wikipedia redirects "[Pass-by-reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass-by-reference)" to "[Evaluation Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy)", which lists [call-by-reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference).

Using "[call-by-reference](http://books.google.com/books?id=x-QOAAAAIAAJ&q=call-by-reference&dq=call-by-reference&lr=&as_drrb_is=b&as_minm_is=0&as_miny_is=&as_maxm_is=0&as_maxy_is=1971&as_brr=0&ei=3DEcS7HYLp7AzgSljYWMAg)" as a search term in Google Books finds a snippet from
"[The Main Features of CPL](http://comjnl.oxfordjournals.org/cgi/content/abstract/6/2/134)" from The Computer Journal, August 1963; 6: 134 - 143 (British Computer Society)

> Three modes of parameter call are possible; call by **value** (which is equivalent to the ALGOL call by value), call by **substitution** (equivalent to ALGOL call by name), and call by **reference**.  In the latter case, the LH value of the actual parameter is handed over; this corresponds to the "call by simple name" suggested by Strachey and Wilkes (1961). Note the correspondence to the three kinds of initialization...

This latter "call by name" is likely the same terminology as was used in the Algol 60 specification, which Stephen C earlier pointed out in this thread.

(I think "[Strachey and Wilkes](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=366813.366816&coll=portal&dl=ACM&CFID=66988950&CFTOKEN=86272055)" is from CACM 1961 but I don't have access to any source text to verify.)

Comment: Well, the ACM Portal citation page you linked for "Strachey & Wilkes" *says* that it is from CACM vol 4 issue 11 (Nov 1961).

Answer (score 2):

I *THINK* it dates back to PASCAL, probably farther.

The original FORTRAN passed arguments by reference: passing the address of the variable, array, or matrix.

ALGOL-60 passed by name or by value.  Call-by-name turned out to be a huge mistake, that taught programming language designers a LOT about what NOT to do.  PASCAL passed parameters by value or by reference, depending on whether the parameter was marked VAR (pass by reference) or not (pass by value).

Comment: Great answer! So I guess Fortran came in 57, and Pascal in the early 70s? Did they use the term "reference" or just the concept.

Comment: @Paul - they used different terminology; see my answer

Comment: As a note, the Pascal Revised Report ( http://www.fh-jena.de/~kleine/history/languages/Wirth-PascalRevisedReport.pdf ) does not mention "pass-by-reference" and instead uses "variable reference." (Section 9.1.2)

Answer (score 2):

The earliest uses of the term "reference" as in "pass by reference" are probably lost in dim antiquity. Certainly, FORTRAN passes its parameters by reference and always has done.

A mention of "call by name" reminds me of a Nickolas Wirth (inventor of Pascal) joke (probably the only one):

"Professor, how do you pronounce your surname?"

"If you call by name, it is V-I-R-T, but if you call by value it is W-O-R-T-H"

And people say programmers have no sense of humor!

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that you could trace it back to [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) which had (and still has) [pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computing)) as well as reference and dereferencing operators.

Comment: I've never heard the term "reference" used in relation to C.

Comment: "The C **Reference** Manual" (* ahem * ;) ) from 1975 (see http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/cman.pdf ) uses "reference" in several places: "since a reference to an array in any context (in particular as an actual parameter) is taken to mean a pointer to the first element of the array", "references to the same external identifier are references to the same object", and at least once other place. I don't have a searchable copy of K&R or of ANSI C handy.

Comment: Fair enough, though I seem unable to retract my downvote. Sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

I'd always thought that the idea was to distinguish between a pointer and reference.  References will point to the object wherever it is.

A pointer is to an address in memory however in managed languages this can change.  So you must have an abstraction via the reference to ensure your code always works.  eg. you couldn't just write reference++ when using arrays in a managed language as the garbage collector can move your array.  Please note I'm well aware of pinning and unsafe code in c# :).

As my java tutor had explained it to me as well, the other key "concept" with a reference is that you can't manipulate it.  Pointers are for the programmer to manage, references are for the compiler/runtime to manage.

Answer (score 1):

The use of the term 'reference' was and is inconsistent.

- In some instances, it is a tangible entity, like the Simula/Delphi/Java/C# object references. You can compare them (with null and with each other)  and pass them as parameters (by value or by reference).
- Most languages support reference as a mode of parameter passing, in a totally opaque way.
- C++ is the only language (that I know off) that extends this opaque model and lets you have reference fields and variables (`int& r = i;`).

For one thing, this means that C++ references  are very different from C# references.

I think we are missing some jargon here to distinguish between these two different forms of 'reference'.

Also see [SO: History of public/private/protected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334451/history-of-public-private-protected).

Comment: Hmmm, off the top of my head Simula is late 60s (67?) so it seems to be the first of the "new uses" of "reference" to mean a managed object. Does the seem accurate (I don't know how "managed" it was)?

Comment: Paul, see the link. Simula (1967) lead the path to 'reference types'. But Not yet 'managed' in the sense of type-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, in the '60s (yeah, into the  '70s), "reference" meant using the name of something. This agrees with the usage of the older philosophical and linguistic terms "referent" and "reference".  From [Fortran 77](http://www.fh-jena.de/~kleine/history/languages/ansi-x3dot9-1978-Fortran77.pdf):

> ### 2.12 Reference
>
> A variable, array element, or substring reference is the appearance of a variable, array 
>   element, or substring name, respectively, in a statement in a context requiring the value 
>   of that entity to be used during the execution of the executable program. When a 
>   reference to an entity is executed, its current value is available. In this standard, the act of 
>   defining an entity is not considered a reference to that entity.
>
> A procedure reference is the appearance of a procedure name in a statement in a context 
>   that requires the actions specified by the procedure to be executed during the execution of 
>   the executable program. When a procedure reference is executed, the procedure must be 
>   available.

Comment: This seems to be talking in the sense of "dereference", as opposed to "call-by-reference". Is there another use of the term reference?

Comment: Before references were called references, and when "call-by-reference" was called "association by name" (as Stephen C points out), "reference" had a different use. Between the '60s and now, the meaning of "reference" changed.

Comment: The above and Stephen's answer (especially point 3) suggest a possible etymology: "association by name" was a more restrictive version of "call by name" that only allowed variable references (in the sense of "that which names something") to be associated with dummy arguments. Whether there's any truth to this depends on how explicit the difference between the two calling semantics was back in the day, and whether or not anyone cared to make the two more distinct.